# Inno Setup Create dependency between custom check boxes

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have a custom page `SelectPage` that I am creating two custom check boxes on. The relevant parts of the code from `InitializeWizard` procedure are below:

```pascal
//Define the Restart Services Checkbox
  RestartServicesCheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with RestartServicesCheckBox do
    begin
      Parent := SelectPage.Surface;
      Caption := 'Restart Services';
      Left := OptionsLabel.Left;
      Top := OptionsLabel.Top + ScaleY(20);
      Checked := True;
    end;
//Define the Restart Server Checkbox
  RestartServerCheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with RestartServerCheckBox do
    begin
      Parent := SelectPage.Surface;
      Caption := 'Restart Server';
      Left := OptionsLabel.Left;
      Top := RestartServicesCheckBox.Top + ScaleY(22);
      Checked := False
    end;
```

This works and I get the check boxes that I want and they perform the actions that I assign to them. What I am struggling to work out is how to assign a dependency between the two, so that if one is checked, the other is automatically unchecked. However, I do not want a radio buttons type dependency, as both checkboxes might need to be unchecked. I was looking at trying to intercept the `OnClick` event something like this:

```pascal
var
  DefaultOnClick: TNotifyEvent;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
//Store the original OnClick event procedure and assign custom procedure
  DefaultOnClick := WizardForm.TCheckBox.OnClick;
  WizardForm.TCheckBox.OnClick := @OnClick;
end;

//Uncheck and Restart Services if Restart Server is checked and vice versa
procedure UpdateOptions();
begin
  with RestartServicesCheckBox do
    begin
      if RestartServicesCheckBox.Checked then
        begin
          Checked := False;
        end;
    end;
  with RestartServerCheckBox do
    begin
      if RestartServerCheckBox.Checked then
        begin
          Checked := False;
        end;
    end;
end;

//Update the options check boxes if the states change and restore the original event handler procedures
procedure OnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DefaultOnClick(Sender);
  UpdateOptions;
end;
```

However, I do not know what the full event name is that I need to intercept. It clearly isn't `WizardForm.TCheckBox.OnClick` anyway. What would this event name be and will this method work? Alternatively, is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the `TCheckBox.OnClick` event that you need to use.

```pascal
var
  RestartServicesCheckBox: TNewCheckBox;
  RestartServerCheckBox: TNewCheckBox;

procedure RestartServicesCheckBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if RestartServicesCheckBox.Checked then
    RestartServerCheckBox.Checked := False;
end;

procedure RestartServerCheckBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if RestartServerCheckBox.Checked then
    RestartServicesCheckBox.Checked := False;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  // Define the Restart Services Checkbox
  RestartServicesCheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with RestartServicesCheckBox do
  begin
    ...
    Checked := True;
    OnClick := @RestartServicesCheckBoxClick;
  end;

  // Define the Restart Server Checkbox
  RestartServerCheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with RestartServerCheckBox do
  begin
    ...
    Checked := False;
    OnClick := @RestartServerCheckBoxClick;
  end;
end;
```

---

Though I think that three radio buttons might be better:

- Do not restart
- Restart service only
- Restart server

Comment: Thanks Martin. That is exactly what I needed to know. Radio buttons would be fine in this situation normally, but the third option, to do nothing (not restart anything) is meant not to be obvious (i.e. not advertised as an option) as it should only need to be used under rare circumstances, hence the reason for using check boxes.